# Extending a class with multiple constructors having differing behavior

Tags: java, constructor

Given a Class with multiple constructors

```
class Food {
    int fibre_count;
    int flavour_amount;

    PreservationProcess preserve;

    public Food( int fibre_count, int flavour_amount){
           this.fibre_count = fibre_count;
           this.flavor_amount = flavor_amount;

           preserve = new PreservationProcess("Freshly Picked");

           /*do some other complicated thing that you do _not_ want done in
             the other constructor*/

    }

    public Food (int fibre_count, int flavour_ammount, PreservationProcess preserve){
           this.fibre_count = fibre_count;
           this.flavor_amount = flavor_amount;
           this.preserve = preserve;
           this.flavour_amount *= preserve.getFlavourModifier();
    }
}
```

and a subclass

```
class Broccoli extends Food {
    int vitamin_count;

    SomeOtherObj = SO_Obj;
    int branch_count;

    Broccoli(int fibre_count, int flavor_amount, int vitamin_count){

        super(fibre_count, flavour_amount);

        /*common code between the two constructors \/  \/  \/ */
        this.vitamin_count = vitamin_count;

        SO_Obj = new SomeOtherObject();
        branch_count = 4;
        greenness = 13;
        /*common code between the two constructors /\  /\  /\ */
    }

    Broccoli(int fibre_count, int flavor_amount, PreservationProcess preserve, int vitamin_count){

        super(fibre_count, flavour_amount, preserve);

        /*common code between the two constructors \/  \/  \/ */
        this.vitamin_count = vitamin_count;
        SO_Obj = new SomeOtherObject();
        branch_count = 4;
        greenness = 13;
        /*common code between the two constructors /\  /\  /\ */
    }


}
```

What is the accepted way to include the code shared between the two broccoli constructors? It seems that my options, are either mainatain two separeate copies of the same code in the separate functions, or, create an "init()" or "construct()" function that holds the shared code once, and is called from each constructor. Are there any other options I am missing?

What is generally accepted as the cleanest way to deal with this situation (I'm looking for best practices, not opinions on what people think is best.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can call `this(param1,param2)` to invoke one constructor from the other.

```
Broccoli(int fibre_count, int flavor_amount, int vitamin_count){
    this (fibre_count,flavor_amount,some_default_preserve,vitamin_count);
}
```

You should always call the constructor with more parameters from the contsructor with less parameters, and give default values to the additional parameters.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am looking for. I understand that this is good practice when one constructor provides a superset of the functionality of another constructor, but in this case the two parent constructors provide separate functionality that is mutually exclusive to one another. In this case, your answer will not work.

Comment: @zzxx: The constructors in `Food` are doing some complicated stuffs. IMHO, it would be better to move those code into some static-factory methods, which you could give some descriptive names. For somebody doing `new Food(...)` might not be that obvious what they are doing.

Comment: If the constructors provide separate mutually exclusive functionality, they really should probably be constructors for two different classes.  This is just an all-round bad design.

Comment: @BheshGurung This example given is a contrived one, and yes, rather awkward, but it was for brevity's sake. In reality I am extending a class from a library which I have no control of the code. In particular the View class of the Android API

Comment: @DonRoby My prior comment relates to your comment as well. Thanks :)

Comment: @zzxx: If that's the case then I wouldn't worry too much about the best practice, instead try to come with something that at least gets the job done first.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to call the other constructor using this(..) but if only a few lines of code is common between two constructors then the only option I think is to implement a common method and call the method from the constructors.

Comment: As per my comment on Eran's answer, this only work when one of the super's constructors provides a superset of the functionality of the other constructor. This is not the case in my example.

Comment: Agree. In such cases you should have a separate method to have the common code and you can call the method from all other constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the code in one constructor and call it from another by using

this (parameters list);

Hopefully an if else block is enough to differentiate between different flows.

Comment: As per my comment on Eran's answer, this only work when one of the super's constructors provides a superset of the functionality of the other constructor. This is not the case in my example.